# Why do entities need keys in Appengine datastore

Tags: google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb

What is the usage of keys in the appengine datastore: I am new to Appengine, any info on it would be great.

Comment: "Each entity is identified by its kind, which categorizes the entity for the purpose of queries, and **a key that uniquely identifies it within its kind.**" - https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/

Comment: I am having difficulty understanding some terms, What exactly is a "kind"? Is there anything that you can compare it to with regards to SQL ? Thanks

Comment: No you shouldn't compare with SQL, contrast maybe.  The best way of moving forward when trying to understand how the appengine datastore works is thoughing out everything you know about SQL. It is one of the many NoSQL platforms out there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Comparison

To keep things simple, let's assume MySQL stores all the rows of a table in a single file. That way, it can find all the rows by scanning that file.

App Engine's datastore (BigTable) does not have a concept of tables. Each entity (~row in MySQL) is stored separately. *[It can also have a individual structure (~columns).]* Because entities are not connected in any way, there is no "default" method to go through all of them. Each entity needs an ID and **must be indexed**.

## Key Structure

A key consists of:

- App ID (the closest thing in MySQL is a **database**).
- Kind (the closest thing in MySQL is a **table**).
- ID or name (the closest thing in MySQL is a **primary key**).
- (Optionally) Parent key (all the above of another entity). *(Details omitted for the sake of simplicity.)*

Please note that what is meant by **the closest thing is conceptual similarity**. **Technically, these things are not related.** In MySQL, databases and tables represent actual storage structures. In BigTable they are just IDs, and the storage is actually flat, i.e. every entity is essentially a file.

In other words, **identity-wise**, `a key` is to `an entity` as `the database + table + primary key` are to `a row` in a MySQL table.

## Key's Responsibilities

An entity's key:

- States what application the entity belongs to.
- What kind (class, table) it is of.
- By the means of the above *and* either a numeric key ID or a textual key name, identifies the entity uniquely.
- (Optionally) What the parent entity of the entity is. *(Details omitted for the sake of simplicity.)*

## Usage

So that you can retrieve all entities of a kind, App Engine automatically builds indexes. That means App Engine maintains a list of all your entities. More specifically, it maintains a list of your entities' keys.
Complex indexes may be defined to run queries on multiple properties (~columns).

In contrast to MySQL, every BigTable query requires an index. Whenever a query is run, the corresponding index is scanned to find the entities that meet the query's conditions, and then the individual entities are retrieved by key.

A common high-level use is to identify an entity in a URL, as every key can be represented as a URL-safe string. When an entity's key is passed in the URL, the entity can be retrieved unambiguously, as the key identifies it uniquely.

Moreover, retrieving an entity by its key is strongly consistent, as opposed to queries on indexes, which means that when entity is retrieved by its key, it's guaranteed to be the latest version.

## Tips

- Every entity stored in BigTable has a key. Such a key may be programmatically created in your application and given an arbitrary key name. If it's not, an numeric ID will be allocated transparently, as the entity is being stored.
- Once an entity is stored, its key may not be changed.
- The optional parent component might be used to define a hierarchy of entities, but what it's really important for is transactions and strong consistency.

  - Entities that share a parent are said to belong to the same entity group.
  - Queries within a group are strongly consistent.
- Just to reiterate, retrieving an entity by its key or querying an index by a parent key are strongly consistent. Retrieving entities in other ways (e.g. by a query on a property) is eventually consistent.

## Glossary

- Entity - a single key-value document.
- Eventual consistency - retrieving an entity (often a number of them) without the guarantee that the replication has completed, which may result in some entities being an old version and some being missing, as they have not yet been brought from the server they were stored on.
- Key - an entity's ID.
- Kind - arbitrary textual name of a class of entities, such as User or Article.
- Key ID - a numeric identifier of a key. Usually automatically allocated.
- Key name - a textual identifier of a key.
- Strong consistency - retrieving an entity in such a way that its latest version is retrieved.

*(I intentionally used MySQL in the examples, as I'm much more familiar with it than with any other relational database.)*

Comment: Can I create an entity without a key ? eg
`testing = Testing(column_1=self.request.get('zipcode'),column_2=self.request.get('something'))` 
vs with a key like
`testing = Testing(parent=ndb.Key("1","1"),column_1=self.request.get('zipcode'),column_2=self.request.get('something'))`

what is the difference above??

Comment: Yes, you can create an entity without providing a Key. What would happen here is that App Engine Datastore will auto assign a Key.

Comment: I've added a little info about creating entities and about parent entities. I hope that's useful.

Answer (score 0):

Please read https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/#Java_Entities ... you may want to delete your question and ask again after you have studied this documentation section.

(This is meant to help you, not complain.)